# Check for Rails in gem initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building a gem that has some conditional logic on the presence/absence of Ruby on Rails. Some pseudo-code from `gem_name/lib/gem_name.rb`

```
# do stuff for all situations

if [Rails is present]
  # do extra rails stuff
end
```

What's the standard way of performing such a check inside a gem?

Comment: Note that, depending on your use case, you may wish to detect ActiveRecord or some other Rails library instead. Also, generally speaking I would prefer manual init code to magical code.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with:

```
if defined?(Rails)
  ...
end
```

Find the documentation for `defined?` here: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-defined-3F

Comment: Where is that method defined? I cannot seem to locate it on `ruby-doc.org`